# C# can picture boxes store values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used the following code to make a picture box.

```
PictureBox[,] pb = new PictureBox[3, 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    pb[i,j] = new PictureBox();
                    pb[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 150 + 100, j * 150 + 100);
                    pb[i, j].Width = 150;
                    pb[i, j].Height = 150;
                    pb[i, j].Visible = true;
                    pb[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    pb[i, j].BringToFront();
                    this.Controls.Add(pb[i, j]);
                }
            }
```

This code is used to create a board for a guessing game where they guess which box the ship is.
I tried to use the code

```
pb[I,j]="N";
```

It comes up with an error so I'm wondering if it is even possible to assign a picture box a value or if I would have to create a board using 2d array.

Comment: You can use the `Tag` property of a control to store anything.

Comment: "It comes up with an error" – WHICH error and what kind of error (compilation, runtime)?

Comment: To attract more helpful answers please respond to comments asking for more information (like the comment above this one). To better understand why your question is receiving so many downvotes, make sure you have read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Generally, people really do want to help and the site guidelines are there to make the best use of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is **C# can picture boxes store values?**

The answer is *yes* it is possible and one way is using the `Tag` property of `PictureBox` as LarsTech mentions. But looking at your code and use case, you would probably benefit from making a custom PictureBox that can store a values like "N" or any *other* kind of value in app-specific ways.

This minimal example has only one custom property, but you can have as many as you want. They can be whatever Type you need and given names that self-document their intended purpose.

```
class CustomPictureBox : PictureBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    object _value = "Empty";
    public object Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_value, value))
            {
                _value = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
                // Demo purposes only:
                MessageBox.Show($"New value is {value}");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

At this point you could meaningfully assign `pb[I,j].Value="N"`.

---

**Example**

Add a 3x3 `TableLayoutPanel` to the main form and initialize it:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int col = 0; col < tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < tableLayoutPanel.RowCount; row++)
            {
                var ship = new CustomPictureBox
                {
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                    Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF,
                    Margin = new Padding(1),
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                };
                ship.Click += onAnyClickShip;
                tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(ship, col, row);
            }
        }
        // Tests
        buttonSetValue.Click += onClickButtonSetValue;
        buttonSetImage.Click += onClickButtonSetImage;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

Set the value of the center square to "N" using `cpb.Value="N"`.

```
private void onClickButtonSetValue(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomPictureBox cpb = 
        (CustomPictureBox) tableLayoutPanel
        .GetControlFromPosition(1, 1);
    cpb.Value = "N";
}
```

[image: set value]

---

Set the image of the center square:

```
private void onClickButtonSetImage(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imagePath = Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "Images",
        "smiley.png");

    CustomPictureBox cpb = 
        (CustomPictureBox)tableLayoutPanel
        .GetControlFromPosition(1, 1);
    cpb.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
}
```

[image: set image]

---

Click on the center square.

```
private void onAnyClickShip(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is CustomPictureBox cpb)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Current cell value is {cpb.Value}");
    }
}
```

[image: click smiley]

But click on any other cell:

[image: click other]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/picture-box-with-value.git) this sample.