# How can i find the background image name of button

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry if i did anything wrong regarding the content, this is my second question here.
I have a button that i dynamically set the background to lets say an image called "x.jpg" How can i retrieve just the "x" from the background image using c# (winforms)?

I have tired the bellow line but it doesnt return the value i wanted.
`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((Button_)Controls["Name"].BackgroundImage.ToString())`
I have also tried using the .Tag attribute but it didnt work either.
`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((Button_)Controls["Name"].Tag.ToString())`

Basically im creating a tic tac toe using 3x3 buttons.

When you click on a button the background changes depending on whos turn is it. It changes to "X" or "O" accordingly.

Im trying to check whether a row has been filled with the same symbol, by getting the backgroundimage name and checking all the buttons in the row have the same background.

Also, as cordinates, the buttons are named 00 ,01, 02 the ones on the first row, 10,11,12 the buttons on the second row etc.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Quite similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77331540/5114784

Comment: Images don't have names, only files that store an image have one.  Be sure to explain why you need this to work to get help.

Comment: I suggest you instead store a `bool` value int the`Tag` property when you set the image, then you can check that value to see what image it's using.

Comment: Or you could create an `enum`, like `enum ImageEnum{None, X, O}` then you have all the infor you want in that enum. To Check, use `(ImageEnum)Controls["Name"].Tag`.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74999920/5438626) might give you some ideas.